# $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic equation.

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

$ω≠1$ and $ω^{13}=1$. If $\alpha=ω+ω^3+ω^4+ω^{−4}+ω^{−3}+ω^{−1}$ and $\beta=ω^2+ω^5+ω^6+ω^{−6}+ω^{−5}+ω^{−2}$, then quadratic equation, whose roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is:

I tried finding the sum and product of roots and placing in the equation $x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+(\alpha\cdot\beta)=0$ but I was not able to solve for it.

Answer (score 1):

By the formula for a finite geometric series,

$$\alpha + \beta = \sum_{i=-6}^{-1} \omega^i + \sum_{i=1}^6 \omega^i =  \sum_{i=7}^{12} \omega^i + \sum_{i=1}^{6} \omega^i =\frac{(1-\omega^{13})}{1 - \omega} -1 =  -1 \tag{$\omega^{13} =1$}$$

For the product $\alpha \beta$, note that $\omega^n = \overline{\omega^{-n}}$. Taking $\omega$ as $e^{2 i \pi /13} = \cos(2\pi /13) + i \sin(2\pi /13)$ for example, $\alpha = 2 \left(\cos(2 \pi/13) + \cos(6 \pi/13)+\cos(8 \pi/13)\right)$ and you can do the same for $\beta$. Then you can use the product-to-sum formula $\cos A \cos B = \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A-B) + \cos(A+B) \right)$: by expanding the brackets, there are nine terms in this form.

Comment: Using a calculator, you should get $x^2 - 3$ as the answer.

Comment: I think you missed a 1 in the sum as there is none with power 0.As the answer is x^2+x-3=0

Comment: Oh right, I miscounted and thought there were $13$ terms.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
1+\alpha+\beta = 1+\omega+\omega^2+\cdots+\omega^{12}=0
$$
and so $\alpha+\beta=-1$. Therefore, $\alpha\beta=-(\alpha+\alpha^2)=-3$.

Unfortunately, I can't see shortcut to compute $\alpha+\alpha^2$ except by [expanding it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomialremainder%5B%28x%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E10%2Bx%5E12%29%5E2%2B%28x%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E10%2Bx%5E12%29%2Cx%5E12%2Bx%5E11%2Bx%5E10%2Bx%5E9%2Bx%5E8%2Bx%5E7%2Bx%5E6%2Bx%5E5%2Bx%5E4%2Bx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1%2Cx%5D).